# "Exception thrown: read access violation" when I'm trying to assign a vector to vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function that return vector of object pointers here:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> STile::ReadFile(const std::string filePath)
{
    std::ifstream infile(workDir.Get() + filePath);
    Tile tile;

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> tileObjects;

    while (infile >> tile.x >> tile.y >> tile.tileID)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Object> tileObject;
        auto sprite = tileObject->addComponent<CSprite>();
        sprite->SetTextureAllocator(&textureAllocator);
        sprite->Load(workDir.Get() + "blocks.png");
        sprite->SetTextureRect(0, 0, 16, 16);
        tileObject->transform->setPosition(tile.x, tile.y);

        tileObjects.emplace_back(tileObject);
    }

    return tileObjects;
}
```

And now I'm trying to assign returned vector to new vector here:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> levelTiles = tileSystem.ReadFile("cord.txt");
```

The result is exception "Exception thrown: read access violation." Any suggestion ? Thanks for help :)

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Object> tileObject;` creates an empty shared pointer, i.e. the equivalent to `nullptr`. Hence the access in the next line dereferences a nullptr. Instead use `auto tileObject = std::make_shared();`.

Comment: @n314159 so can i use make_shared for vector like for single object ?

Comment: A vector is a single object, so yes.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  Is exist other way to do this ?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Does it compile? Does the error still come? Something else: you should probably declare `sprite` as `auto&` when you want to change the sprite belonging to `tileObject` and not just a copy thereof.

Comment: Try `auto tileObject = make_shared<Object>()`

Comment: It's work fine, thanks.